# Basic Shoes: Input through an edit line

Tags: ruby, shoes

How does one make an edit line in shoes that takes the user's input and stores it in a variable after they hit enter (similar to the console) rather than making them click a button.
I tried to use keypress and to detect the return key then clear the edit line and store it's .text in a variable. However, the system only detects the key when I don't have a cursor in the edit line.
  Does the keypress only detect in specific slots and not in an edit line? Can anyone clarify what is going on here? Also, is there a better way to input text like the console?

Answer (score 1):

```
Shoes.app do
  @edit = edit_line
  button "Add" do
    para @edit.text
  end
end
```

This is simple example, I hope it is what you were looking for